# Prisma models with various relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

The code is a bunch of Prisma models, starting from `Move`. This model stores data about pokémon moves as can be obtained from the PokéAPI. Further models are shown in order of appearance inside the `Move` model, with comments for context.

Relations are as follows:

- one move to many effect entries
- one move to many flavor text entries
- one move to many names (in different languages)
- one ailment to many moves (since several moves apply effects like 'paralysis')
- one move category to many moves
- one move to many machines (several machines may teach the same move; haven't found any example yet, but that's how the API lays the data out)

Example:

- move query [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/20/ ('bind')](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/20)
- ailment [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-ailment/0/ ('none')](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-ailment/0/)
- category [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-category/0/ ('damage')](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-category/0/)
- damage class [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-damage-class/2/ ('physical')](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-damage-class/2/)
- machine [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/machine/1/ ('tm00': 'mega-punch')](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/machine/1/)

I have not reproduced all of the provided data inside the models, only what I want to show in the UI.
All fields related to 'contests' (i.e. `contest_combos`, contest_effects`,` contest_type`and`super_contest_effect`), and fields for which I could not find example data, like` stat_changes`were ignored. Many`url`fields were also ignored, since they usually come together with a`name` field that would result in a faster query in the local DB, as opposed to fetching from the PokéAPI again.

What ways are there to improve these models?

```js
// move names for game versions the move is available in
model Move {
  id                Int               @id
  accuracy          Int
  DamageClass       DamageClass       @relation(fields: [damageClassId], references: [id])
  damageClassId     Int
  effectChance      Int
  effectEntries     EffectEntry[]
  flavorTextEntries FlavorTextEntry[]
  generation        String
  learnedByPokemon  String[]
  machines          Machine[]
  name              String            @unique
  names             MoveName[]
  Pokemons          Pokemon[]
  power             Int
  pp                Int
  priority          Int
  target            String
  type              String
  // the next fields are part of the move's 'meta' data
  // usually it's own object, but kept it here instead of creating a whole new model
  Ailment           Ailment           @relation(fields: [ailmentId], references: [id])
  ailmentId         Int
  ailmentChance     Int
  Category          MoveCategory      @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId        Int
  critRate          Int
  drain             Int
  flinchChance      Int
  healing           Int
  maxHits           Int?
  maxTurns          Int?
  minHits           Int?
  minTurns          Int?
  statChance        Int
}

// paralysis, sleep, freeze, burn, poison, confusion, infatuation, trap, nightmare, torment, disable, yawn
// heal-block, no-type-immunity, leech-seed, embargo, perish-song, ingrain, unknown, none
model Ailment {
  id    Int           @id
  moves String
  name  String
  names AilmentName[]
  Move  Move[]
}

// ailment name in all available languages
model AilmentName {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  language  String
  name      String
  Ailment   Ailment @relation(fields: [ailmentId], references: [id])
  ailmentId Int
}

// one of: status, physical, special
model DamageClass {
  id           Int                      @id
  descriptions DamageClassDescription[]
  name         String
  names        DamageClassName[]
  // moves of this damage class
  moves        Move[]
}

// damage class descriptions by language
model DamageClassDescription {
  description   String      @unique
  language      String
  DamageClass   DamageClass @relation(fields: [damageClassId], references: [id])
  damageClassId Int
}

model DamageClassName {
  language      String
  name          String      @unique
  DamageClass   DamageClass @relation(fields: [damageClassId], references: [id])
  damageClassId Int
}

// explanation of the move's effect (not shown in game?)
model EffectEntry {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  effect      String @unique
  language    String
  shortEffect String
  Move        Move   @relation(fields: [moveId], references: [id])
  moveId      Int
}

// in-game move description, per language / game version
model FlavorTextEntry {
  id           Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  flavorText   String @unique
  language     String
  Move         Move   @relation(fields: [moveId], references: [id])
  moveId       Int
  versionGroup String
}

// those items containing a move to teach your pokémon
model Machine {
  id           Int    @id
  item         String @unique
  moveName     String
  Move         Move   @relation(fields: [moveId], references: [id])
  moveId       Int
  versionGroup String
}

// one of: damage, ailment, net-good-stats, heal, damage+ailment, swagger, damage+lower, damage+raise
// damage+heal, ohko (one-hit KO), whole-field-effect, field-effect, force-switch, unique
model MoveCategory {
  descriptions MoveCategoryDescription[]
  id           Int                       @id
  moves        Move[]
  name         String
}

// move category description in all available languages
model MoveCategoryDescription {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  description String
  language    String
  Category    MoveCategory @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId  Int
}

model MoveName {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  language String
  name     String @unique
  Move     Move   @relation(fields: [moveId], references: [id])
  moveId   Int
}
```